# How to lockdown a mysite page for some users

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, my-site, user-profile-property, profile-sync

import profile services is configured and running into my sp 2010 farm. But for some requirements I need to Lockdown a mysite page properties for a specific user , so that when import profile runs, does not update properties from AD for some users

Is there any way to this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this procedure to configure the user permissions for personal and social features.

To enable users or groups to use personal and social features follow there steps:

1. Verify that you have the following administrative credentials:

   To use the SharePoint Central Administration website to enable users or groups to use personal and social features, you must be a member of the Farm Administrators group, or you must have been delegated permission to administer the User Profile service application that is running in the farm. For more information, see Delegate administration of User Profile service applications in SharePoint Server 2013.
2. In Central Administration, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
3. In the list of service applications, click User Profile Service Application.
4. On the Manage Profile Service: User Profile Service Application page, in the People group, click Manage User Permissions.
5. On the Permissions for User Profile Service Application page, select a user or group account, and then click Remove.
6. In the Permissions for box, check the feature or features that you want the user or group to be able to use, and then click OK.

Source: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=222

Comment: And this Will prevent import profile service to update user properties ? Maybe I'm wrong but I don't think is what I asked

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this out of the box. You could try messing with the individuals permissions in AD such that the User Profile Sync account cannot read the user and thus would not perform the sync, but I have never tried such a thing.

A simpler solution would be to just write a script that runs periodically to "fix" the individuals Profile, restoring it to the desired state.